# How do I get sum of a field in solr in 8.11.1 version

Tags: function, solr, sum

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
    {
      "total_amountA": 10,
      "total_amountB": 5,
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "total_amountA": 10,
      "total_amountB": 5,
      "id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to get the sum of all tatal_amount.
like this -> total_amountA : 20, total_amountB : 10

how can i get the sum of all value..? plese help me

Answer (score 1):

[The Stats Component gives you a set of statistics for a given field](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/the-stats-component.html) for a given query.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/select?q=your:query&stats=true&stats.field=total_amount
```

Should give you an additional `stats` key in the response with sum among the values calculated.

Comment: can i ask one more question,,? i have updated my quetion..

Comment: If you want stats to be calculated for several fields, add another `stats.field=total_amountB` to the query.